# Consulta sobre rango de tiempo en SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buen día, Tengo que realizar una consulta sobre la generación de alarmas, quiero saber cuantos segundos permanece activa (Columna: EventTime) cada periodo de encendido y apagado (Columna: Message)  , del tiempo que pasa en ese lapso quiero generar un total para mostrar el tipo de alarmas activas y cuanta fue su duración, más no encuentro la manera de hacerlo ya que no cuentan con un ID o algo que me pueda ayudar a ligar los datos, agradecería su ayuda!

Comment: Estimado, como comentario le puedo decir, que una de las tareas básicas que se debe realizar en cada modelado de datos, es la de incorporar una llave identificadora, que pueda permitir asilar, comparar y agrupar datos. Si lo que quiere es calcular  el tiempo que cada tipo de alarma o sector estuvo activo en un periodo dado, debe identificarlas con un ID. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario! así es y es lo que complica el análisis de la información, así como la cantidad de registros que son miles y es mas complejo el definir el periodo  de activación, algo bueno saldrá de esto, mínimo el aprendizaje de no hacerlo de nuevo jajaja

Comment: Estimado, el hecho de que su modelo de datos o el motor de base de datos  tenga que analizar y/o procesar miles de registros, no esta fuera del alcance de este maravilloso invento. En otras palabras, para eso están hechas las bases de datos, para disponibilizar y persistir datos, y la cantidad de estos, que puedan almacenar, solo estará restringido por el almacenamiento del servidor. La capacidad y/o eficiencia que tenga su desarrollo de manejar esta información dependerá de otros factores como diseño de la misma, cursores, correcta utilización de procedimientos, etc. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usar la fecha de la columna EventTime como identificador, ya que la fecha de cada registro seria un valor unico, así crearias la consulta que te obtenga los datos definidos, pero siempre deberias tener a tu dispoción estos datos, pero en teoria funcionaria correctamente como columna "identificadora" en tu proyecto.

No dudes preguntar y Saludos